# Entity Framework Core Lazy loading using proxies does not work (SQLite)

Tags: .net-core, entity-framework-core

When using lazy loading, I expect the child navigation properties not loaded
But I cannot avoid the children being loaded and causing circular reference when serialized as json

`DbContext`:

```
public class SampleDbContext : DbContext
{
    public SampleDbContext(DbContextOptions<SampleDbContext> options: base(options)
    { }

    protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
    {
        optionsBuilder.UseLazyLoadingProxies();
    }

    public DbSet<Parent> Parents { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Child> Children { get; set; }
}
```

Model classes:

```
public class Child
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("Parent")]
    public int ParentId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual Parent parent { get; set; }
}

public class Parent
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Child> children { get; set; }
}
```

Startup:

```
services.AddDbContext<Models.SampleDbContext>(options =>options.UseLazyLoadingProxies().UseSqlite(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));
```

Controller:

```
[HttpGet]
public async Task<List<Models.Parent>> Get()
{
    var sample = _cont.Parents.ToList();
    return sample;
}
```

Using:

- EF Core version: 2.2.1
- Database Provider: Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Sqlite 2.2.1
- Operating system: Win 10
- IDE: Visual Studio 2017

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [ef core docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/related-data#related-data-and-serialization):

> Because EF Core will automatically fix-up navigation properties, you can end up with cycles in your object graph.

...

> If you are using ASP.NET Core, you can configure Json.NET to ignore cycles that it finds in the object graph.

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    ...

    services.AddMvc()
        .AddJsonOptions(
            options => options.SerializerSettings.ReferenceLoopHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore
        );

    ...
}
```

Comment: thanks but how could we say lazy loading works then?